# Read value of server registry key from client application

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, registry

I have a WinForms app that I am using on a local network. I want to read the value of a specific key from the registry of the server -- how can I do this? If I'm a user on the local network, can I get this value from the server? Thanks in advance for any help.

i want to read this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>microsoft>microsoft sql server>SQLEXPRESS>Setup>SQLPATH
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into the [RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) class.  Specifically, the [OpenRemoteBaseKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws.aspx) method.  Be sure to read the remarks, among them: both the server and client have to be running the remote registry service, and the client must have the proper access.  You'll probably want to read the remarks for [RegConnectRemoteKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724840%28VS.85%29.aspx), as well, because that's the underlying function that the .NET wrapper calls.

Comment: you mean the client must have access to read key's value from server??